# Play store install problem

Tags: google

I have a 2look 2LGX05-S with android 4.2. The problem is I can't install anything on the app store because it says insufficient storage. Phone storage has 2.8 GB available, SD card 13.42GB and internal 75.30 MB free. Also in settings I have set that desired and preffered install place to SD card so it saves everything there.

Comment: Try reinstalling the Play Store app or perhaps a factory reset may resolve the issue.

Comment: I can't uninstall it because it is a pre-installed app and a factory reset is not an option and I doubt it will help since I got this phone on my birthday(9 days ago).

Comment: Bumping this lol.